# Is it possible to "reset" docker from previous runs?

Tags: docker, minio

I am fiddling with a MLFlow + MinIO docker set up, at the moment doing it locally and I have nothing important in the docker, I'm just learning.

Trying to update the MinIO docker image to a jan 2023 one, I am greeted with an error message regarding `/data` backends, which *could* be solved using [this issue](https://github.com/minio/docs/issues/660). However, as I said, I'm inexperienced with this stack (so the task seems daunting to me) and also I don't have anything worh saving and/or migrating from the previous docker, so my question is:

> how would I "reset" whatever cache docker has from previous image runs so I start anew?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: Deleting a container will also delete its local filesystem, and if you're mounting external storage into it you should know that from your `docker run -v` or Compose `volumes:` options.  Is there a more specific setup you're having trouble with?